# XmlSerialization of List of mixed type objects in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, arraylist, xmlserializer

i want to Serialize `List<object>` contained specific class i wrote.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

        List<object> ListToSerialize = new List<object>();
        ListToSerialize.Add(new CustomeClass());
        ListToSerialize.Add("");
        ListToSerialize.Add(2);
        ListToSerialize.Add(new int[] { 7, 8, 6 });
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ListToSerialize.GetType());
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, ListToSerialize);
        }
        string Res = stringWriter.ToString();
}
[Serializable]
public class CustomeClass 
{
}
```

i got error :
There was an error generating the XML document.
The type New.CustomeClass was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

i also implemented `IXmlSerializable` interface.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomeClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw null;
    }
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
    }
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString("1");
    }
}
```

and i got bellow error:

The type New.CustomeClass may not be used in this context. To use New.CustomeClass as a parameter, return type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return type, or member must be declared as type New.CustomeClass (it cannot be object). Objects of type New.CustomeClass may not be used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists.

it works when i use `List<CustomeClass>`, but i need to it be `List<object>`.
thanks for your help

Comment: `[Serializable]` is for a different serializer, not of any use here.

Comment: As in  "it does not work with or without it" ?

Comment: i removed [Serializable], so it does not work yet.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `List<object>`? Are you going to put objects of all kinds in that list? Perhaps you should consider a better organisation of your data...

Comment: because i am writing a dynamic code that i don't know which type end-user will choose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it works if removes IXmlSerializable interface.
it is use-full to know that this solution increases time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Although i would definitely recommend not using this kind of code, you can use `XmlSerializer` constructor overload which accepts a `Type[]` of additional types. From [`XmlSerializer Constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the XmlSerializer class that can
>   serialize objects of the specified type into XML documents, and
>   deserialize XML documents into object of a specified type. If a
>   property or field returns an array, the extraTypes parameter specifies
>   objects that can be inserted into the array.

Use it like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        List<object> ListToSerialize = new List<object>();

        ListToSerialize.Add(new CustomeClass());
        ListToSerialize.Add("");
        ListToSerialize.Add(2);
        ListToSerialize.Add(new int[] { 7, 8, 6 });

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ListToSerialize.GetType(), new[] 
        { typeof(int}, typeof(int[]), typeof(string), typeof(CustomeClass) });

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, ListToSerialize);
        }
        string Res = stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. but i can not implement IXmlSerializable interface

Comment: If the answer helped, consider marking it as answer. You can do that by clicking the green check mark under the voting button to the left